# Can't make Spring JMX NotificationListener  work

Tags: java, spring, notifications, jmx

I have configured a ManagedBean using `@ManagedResource` annotation using Spring. And also mapped a JMX `NotificationListener` to this. **But I am seeing that the Listener never gets kicked-off/executed**.

Here are the related configuration files:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="myMBeanServer"
        class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
        <!-- indicate to first look for a server -->
        <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- MBean auto exporter -->
    <bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter"
        lazy-init="false">
        <property name="server" ref="myMBeanServer" />
        <property name="assembler" ref="assembler" />
        <property name="namingStrategy" ref="namingStrategy" />
        <property name="notificationListenerMappings">
            <map>
                <entry key="myMBean"
                    value-ref="myMBeanNotificationListener" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- The assembler -->
    <bean id="assembler"
        class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler">
        <property name="attributeSource" ref="attributeSourceStrategy" />
    </bean>

    <!-- The naming strategy -->
    <bean id="namingStrategy"
        class="org.springframework.jmx.export.naming.MetadataNamingStrategy">
        <property name="attributeSource" ref="attributeSourceStrategy" />
    </bean>

    <!-- The attributeSource strategy -->
    <bean id="attributeSourceStrategy"
        class="org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationJmxAttributeSource" />

    <!-- MyMBean -->
    <bean id="myMBean"
        class="com.sample.MyMBean" />

    <!-- MBean Notification Listener -->
    <bean id="myMBeanNotificationListener"
        class="com.sample.MyMBeanNotificationListener" />
</beans>
```

Here is how the `MyMBean` class looks like:

```
@ManagedResource(description = "My Mbean", objectName = "com.sample:bean=myMBean")
public class MyMBean {

    private boolean isAvailable = true;

    @ManagedAttribute(description = "isAvailable", defaultValue = "true")
    public void setAvailable(boolean flag) {
        this.isAvailable = flag;
    }
}
```

And finally, here's how the `NotificationListener` looks like:

```
public class MyMBeanNotificationListener implements
        NotificationListener {

    @Override
    public void handleNotification(Notification notification, Object handback) {
        System.out.println("In Notification Listener" + notification);
    }

}
```

Any idea why the `NotificationListener` is not getting executed? There isn't any exception thrown by the code.

Has anyone got the JMX `NotificationListener`s working with Spring?

Comment: What do you expect if `MyMBean` doesn't publish notifications?

Comment: axtavt, please check my earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260398/jmx-spring-when-is-a-jmxnotification-broadcasted there someone confirmed that attribute change broadcasts a JMX notification. With the above listener I was hoping to capture that. Are you sure that we need to have a publisher and attribute change does not automatically send notifications? Thanks!

Comment: The article linked in the answer to your previous question clearly says that you need to broadcast `AttributeChangeNotification`s manually.

Answer (score 1):

It's not getting executed because you probabily have lazy-load enabled, just set explicitly set lazy-init to false on JMX beans.

Example: http://java.dzone.com/articles/exposing-pojo-jmx-mbean-easily?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+javalobby/frontpage+(Javalobby+/+Java+Zone)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the notifications appear in jConsole or jVisualVM?

Try changing:

```
<entry key="myMBean" value-ref="myMBeanNotificationListener" />
```

to:

```
<entry key="com.sample:bean=myMBean" value-ref="myMBeanNotificationListener" />
```

If not for notifications, you could simpify the XML above to:

```
<context:mbean-export default-domain="myDomain"/>
```